how to dynamic modify logback SiftingAppender's appender encoder
I want to print different task's log to itself log file. so I use logback SiftingAppender + MDC.put.
this is my xml configuration
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
    <property name="CHARSET" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="DEFAULT_PATTERN" value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS}] [%thread] [%-5p] [%C{0}.%M:%line] - %m%n"/>
    <property name="PATTERN_NO_PATTERN" value="%m%n"/>
    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="logs"/>
    <property name="MAX_HISTORY" value="15"/>


    <appender name="mdcTaskLoggerAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

        <discriminator>
            <key>MDC_LOG_FILE</key>
            <defaultValue>${LOG_PATH}/mdc-task-other.log</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="${MDC_LOG_FILE}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>${MDC_LOG_FILE}</file>
                <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
                <encoder>
                    <charset>${CHARSET}</charset>
                    <pattern>${MDC_LOG_PATTERN:-${DEFAULT_PATTERN}}</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>


    <appender name="consoleLoggerAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <file>${LOG_PATH}/console.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/console-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${CHARSET}</charset>
            <pattern>${PATTERN_DEF}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="mdcTaskLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="mdcTaskLoggerAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleLoggerAppender" />
    </root>

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>
</configuration>

thread A:
    public void run() {
        try {
            MDC.put("MDC_LOG_FILE", "logs/mdc" + i + ".log");
            logger.info("MDCThread is running {}", i);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("MDC_LOG_FILE");
        }
    }

thread B:
    public void run() {
        try {
            MDC.put("MDC_LOG_FILE", "logs/mdc" + i + ".log");
            

            // DEFAULT_PATTERN and MDC_LOG_PATTERN are all not work
            MDC.put("DEFAULT_PATTERN", "%msg%n");
            logger.info("MDCNoPatternThread is running {}", i);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("MDC_LOG_FILE");
            MDC.remove("DEFAULT_PATTERN");
        }
    }

I hope modify fileAppender's encoder pattern.
for example:
Thread A: task1 : write log to task1.log with pattern a
Thread B: task1 : write log to task1.log with pattern b (no need time、thread、line...)
But I found that not work, all thread write log has the default pattern.
How can I fix it?
